# Any way to filter a view by week number?

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-views

I've got several views configured which display data over many years. The data is filtered by Year using a date field as filter criteria. For each year I have attachment views that I need to filter further by week. Rather than determining the exact dates for the weeks of each year and inputting them manually as filter criteria, I'm wondering if there is any way to add a filter criterion to filter by week number, i.e. week 1 thru week 52. That way the only date that needs to be set is the year for each view, and the rest happens automatically according to week number.

Does anyone have any advice/hints for me on this? Thanks very much.

Here is the code i am working with in a views PHP filter:

```
function x_week_start($date) {
$ts = strtotime($date);
$start = (date('w', $ts) == 0) ? $ts : strtotime('last sunday', $ts);
return date('Y-m-d', $start); }

function x_week_end($date) {
$ts = strtotime($date);
$start = (date('w', $ts) == 0) ? $ts : strtotime('last sunday', $ts);
return date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next saturday', $start)); }

$date = '2013-01-14';
$start = x_week_start($date);
$end = x_week_end($date);
$inquiry_date = date('Y-m-d', $data->field_field_inquiry_date[0]['raw']['value']);

if ($inquiry_date <= $start) {return FALSE;}
```

Comment: Your code must be invincible, because I can't see it

Comment: [`date()`](http://php.net/date), see the `W` format option

Comment: @TheCOMPLETEPHPNewbie, this is part of a Drupal 7 Views 3 setup.  I don't have any working custom code for this filter as of yet.

Comment: @DaveRandom, I tried some code using the date function but it's not returning the true or false result for some reason.  Can't seem to determine why it's not working for me.

Comment: @DaveRandom - here is the code I am playing around with as a Views filter criterion using the views php fliter:

Comment: @user1055810 You want `W` (uppercase), not `w`